# Python Staircase (Hackerrank)

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem in Hacker rank and they gave me a staircase challenge. I don't see the difference between my output and theirs. Could anyone help me out?

Here's the link to my problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem.

Here's the code I wrote(only the function, rest were already written):

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    for x in range(n, 0, -1):
         print(" "*(x-1),"#"*(n-x+1))

     

if __name__ == '__main__':
      n = int(input())

  staircase(n)
```

The output screen on the website:

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuZWo.png  This is the link for an image of my output and the expected output on Hackerrank

Comment: It looks like you output 1 space in front of the hashtags more than expected. You could try to replace your print statement with `print(" "*(x-2),"#"*(n-x+1))`?

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks a bunch